# Hide element/component with ngIf not working

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I want to add/remove an error message div based on an array - if the length is not 0 add the div else remove it.

But it does not work - after the div is removed - it is never added.

Why is it not added?

My ts:

```
errorMessages: string[] = [];
company: Company = null;

constructor(private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>) { } // NgRX store

ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select('position')
      .subscribe(currState => {
          this.company = {_id: '1', name: '1'};
          if (!this.company.email) {
            console.log('11111') // printed before and after pressing the close button
            this.errorMessages = ['There was an error fetching the company'];
          }

          // printed before and after pressing the close button

          // printing 'Array [ "There was an error fetching the company" ] 1'. 
          // and after pressing the close button of the message component printing 
          // 'Array [ "There was an error fetching the company" ] 1'
          console.log(this.errorMessages, this.errorMessages.length) 


      });
  }

onClose() {
  this.store.dispatch(new PositionActions.ClearError());
  this.errorMessages = [];
}
```

The html:

```
<app-message-box *ngIf="errorMessages.length" [messages]="errorMessages" (closeMessages)="onClose()"></app-message-box>
{{ errorMessages.length }} // printing '1'. and after pressing the close button of the message component printing '0'
```

Message component ts:

```
  @Input() messages: string[];
  @Output() closeMessages = new EventEmitter<void>();

  onClose() {
    this.closeMessages.emit();
  }
```

Message component html:

```
<div class="message-box">
  <button class="close-button glyphicon glyphicon-remove" (click)="onClose()">
  </button>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let message of messages">
      {{ message }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Will you add more error messages to the `errorMessages` array or will it contain only one message throughout the app lifecycle?

Comment: it might have more. i tried the code above to check why my code does not work, but instead i just got to not know why the code above does not work

Comment: Try adding console.log at the end of onClose method. I think subscribtion code is exectuted first (right after dispatch) and then, at the end, happens this.errorMessages = [] in onClose.

Comment: yea you are right - the ```subscription``` executed before the ```onClose```. do you have any idea how i can make that work? for now i added a check for ```company.email``` in the ```ngIf```